# Xaml StaticResourceExtension vs adding to IList

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, staticresource

```
<MyControl>
    <MyControl.MyList> <!-- IList -->
        <MyListItem />
        <StaticResourceExtension ResourceKey="MyKey1_PointingTo_MyListItem_Instance" />
        <StaticResourceExtension ResourceKey="MyKey2_PointingTo_MyListItem_Instance" />
    </MyControl.MyList>
</MyControl>
```

The above code adds 3 `MyListItem` instances into `MyList` property; this is the correct behavior.
However, if I remove the first item, so only use `StaticResourceExtension`s, I get this exception:

> Additional information: `MyListItem` is not a valid value for property `MyList`.

So it seems to me that the xaml parser can't figure out I want to `Add` items into the `IList`, it thinks I want to assign value to it.

Is there a way to `Add` items into an `IList` in xaml only using `StaticResourceExtension`s?

### Edit

I've made up a runnable project to demostrate the issue: [https://github.com/nvirth/Xaml_StaticResourceExtension_vs_IL‌​ist](https://github.com/nvirth/Xaml_StaticResourceExtension_vs_IL%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bist)

Comment: Your code will provided that the MyList property returns a concrete type such as a List<MyListItem> or ObservableCollection<MyListItem>. Is there any particular reason why the type has to be IList? I don't think you can make it work then unless you create a custom type that implements the IList interface and create an instance of this one in your XAML markup.

Comment: Actually, the type of MyList property is not IList in reality, but since it does not matter, I've written IList into the example code above.
The above example does not create a new IList instance, it just adds the 3 items into an existing one.
The MyList property has an IList instance set in its ctor.
See:

public MyControl()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    MyList = new MyObservableList(/*DefaultItems*/);
}

Comment: It would be helpful if you could post the actual definitions of your types.

Comment: I've made up a runnable project to demostrate the issue: [https://github.com/nvirth/Xaml_StaticResourceExtension_vs_IList](https://github.com/nvirth/Xaml_StaticResourceExtension_vs_IList)